# ListView are increase relativelayout size

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, android-screen-support

I have a listview in inside a RelativeLayout. The size of my relativelayour change according the size of my listview (number of rows). If it has only two rows, the relative layout stays larger. If it has more rows, the relative stays smaller.

This happen only in small devices.

What do I do?

**EDIT: CODE BELOW**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/bg_cinza_transparente_98_porcento"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".AdicionarMarcaModeloActivity" >

<LinearLayout
    style="@style/..."
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/cinza_escuro"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

     <RelativeLayout
         style="@style/..."
         android:orientation="vertical" >

         <TextView
             android:id="@+id/labelCabecalhoMarcaModelo"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
             android:layout_centerVertical="true"
             android:text="Marca"
             android:textColor="@android:color/white"
             android:textSize="22sp" />

         <ImageView
             android:id="@+id/imgCloseMarcaModelo"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
             android:layout_centerVertical="true"
             android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
             android:src="@drawable/bt_close" />

     </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        style="@style/..."
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/branco_gelo"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/labelSubCabecalhoMarcaModelo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:text="SELECIONE A MARCA DO SEU VEÍCULO"
            android:textColor="@color/cinza_escuro_fontes_cabecalho" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    style="@style/..."
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lvMarcaModelo"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:divider="@drawable/line" >
    </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: please add your xml file

Comment: and @style/Pesos_Marca_Modelo_Corpo please

Comment: The styles are: 80 for the relativelayout and 20 for the secont linear layout

Comment: what is layoyt_height for relativelayout?

Comment: height: 0dp and weight: 80dp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem...

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/labelCabecalhoMarcaModelo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Marca"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:textSize="22sp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgCloseMarcaModelo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"/>


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/labelSubCabecalhoMarcaModelo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="SELECIONE A MARCA DO SEU VEÍCULO"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"/>


    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp">

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/lvMarcaModelo"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:divider="@drawable/line" >
        </ListView>

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```